# Gallery is loading all the images but gallery should be load one image at a time

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, android-gallery

i have created a gallery for display images haveing pinchzoom with goto next and previous by touch . i were use to visit https://github.com/kilaka/ImageViewZoom library . i saw Gallery first upload all the images and then it is displaying images which is good activity. but gallery can upload max 4MB images , if images size go to greater than 4MB then it gives us Bitmap outofmemory error. i have used to bitmap.recycle() but it is recycle all the images.

do here any way, so my gallery upload images one by one from sdcard and when i will go to next or previous images by touch , my currently images memory should be delete . and next images should be uploaded in gallery memory . so my gallery can upload a number of images .

this is my code , this code is link from visit https://github.com/kilaka/ImageViewZoom  :-

```
 gallery = new GalleryTouch(this);
       gallery = (GalleryTouch) findViewById(R.id.image);
       gallery.setSpacing(20);
       arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ImageView>(this, -1) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                bookM= position;        return getItem(position); 
                        }
        };

if(!(it.isEmpty() )) {
       Collections.sort(it); 
    for(int i=0; i<it.size();i++) {
            ImageViewTouch imageView = new ImageViewTouch(imageTouch.this);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            final Options options = new Options();
            options.outHeight = (int) scaleHeight; 
            options.outWidth = (int) scaleWidth;   
            options.inScaled = true;
            options.inPurgeable = true;
            options.inSampleSize = 2;
            String photoURL = it.get(i);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoURL,options);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                arrayAdapter.add(imageView); 
        }
       gallery.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
        }
```

Note:-  in this code, "it" is a variable of   List it; and list having a list of path of image from sd card like as sdcard/images/one.jpg , sdcard/images/two.jpg ........ etc.

please expert help me , 
thank you for your important time.